# How to generate a prediction interval from a regression tree rpart object?

Tags: r, tree, prediction

How do you generate a prediction interval from a regression tree that is fit using rpart?

It is my understanding that a regression tree models the response conditional on the mean of the leaf nodes. I don't know how to get the variance for a leaf node from the model, but what I would like to do is simulate using the mean and variance for a leaf node to obtain a prediction interval.

[Predict.rpart()](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf) doesn't give an option for interval.

**Example:** I fit a tree with iris data, but predict doesn't have an option, "interval"

```
> r1 <- rpart(Sepal.Length ~ ., cp = 0.001, data = iris[1:nrow(iris)-1,])
> predict(r1,newdata=iris[nrow(iris),],type = "interval")
Error in match.arg(type) : 
  'arg' should be one of “vector”, “prob”, “class”, “matrix”
```

Comment: I don't think you can get confidence intervals from `rpart`, but you can from `ctree` in the `party` package. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768964/is-it-possible-to-get-a-p-value-for-nodes-in-a-categorical-tree-analysis-with-r/27770269#27770269).

Comment: Actually, would it be possible to use the `where` function to match the row of the dataset with the leaf node and then to use the empirical data to estimate an interval?

Comment: @eipi10 the SO answer you linked concerns p-values of structural change tests, not prediction intervals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not clear to me what confidence intervals would mean for regression trees as those are not classical statistical models like linear models. And I see mainly two uses: characterising the certainty of your tree or characterizing the precision of the prediction for each leaf of the tree. Hereafter an answer for each of these possibilities.

### Characterizing the certainty of your tree

If you are looking for a confidence value for a split node, then `party` provides that directly as it uses permutation tests and statistically determine which variables are most important and the p-value attached to each split. A significant superiority of `party`'s `ctree` function over `rpart` as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22035/party-vs-rpart-vs-for-partitioning-trees-in-r).

### Confidence intervals for set leafs of the regression tree

Third, if you are looking for a confidence of interval for the value in each leaf, then the [0.025,0.975] quantiles interval for the observations in the leaf is most likely what you are looking for. The default plots in `party` takes a similar approach when displaying boxplots for the output value for each leaf:

```
library("party")
r2 <- ctree(Sepal.Length ~ .,data=iris)
plot(r2)
```

[image: example party tree]

Retrieving the corresponding intervals can simply be done by:

```
iris$leaf <- predict(r2, type="node")
CIleaf <- aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length,
                    by=list(leaf=iris$leaf),
                    quantile,
                    prob=c(0.025, 0.25, 0.75, 0.975))
```

And it's easy to visualize:

```
plot(as.factor(CIleaf$leaf), CIleaf[, 2],
     ylab="Sepal length", xlab="Regression tree leaf")
legend("bottomright",
       c(" 0.975 quantile", " 0.75 quantile", " mean", 
         " 0.25 quantile", " 0.025 quantile"),
       pch=c("-", "_", "_", "_", "-"),
       pt.lwd=0.5, pt.cex=c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1), xjust=1)
```

[image: Sepal length variance per regression tree leaf]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps one option is a simple bootstrap of your training data?

```
library(rpart)
library(boot)

trainData <- iris[-150L, ]
predictData <- iris[150L, ]

rboot <- boot(trainData, function(data, idx) {
            bootstrapData <- data[idx, ]
            r1 <- rpart(Sepal.Length ~ ., bootstrapData, cp = 0.001)
            predict(r1, newdata = predictData)
        }, 1000L)

quantile(rboot$t, c(0.025, 0.975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
5.871393 6.766842
```